# Отображение одного пользователя в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

я только начал изучать WPF. В моём проекте есть кабинет пользователей и я хочу вывести в этом кабинете только одного пользователя, я при регистрации автоматически добавляю пользователей в базу данных но хочу чтобы выводился всего 1 пользователь. Пытался реализовать  это через List(на скриншоте), но выводятся все пользователи. Или такое получится только через sql запрос?. Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок пожалуйста объясните. Заранее спасибо[image: Создаю список пользователей]

[image: Через привязку данных заношу в TextBlock]

[image: Через класс User получаю доступ к полям]

[image: Вывод пользователей]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учитесь вставлять текс кода а не скриншоты. И Ваш запрос db.Users.ToList() запрашивает всех пользователей используйте db.Users.Where(...).ToList() чтоб выбрать конкретного пользователя

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak так лучше же `db.Users.Where(...).FirstOrDefault()` если нужен один юзер

Comment: Пользователь обычно идентифицируется по ID или по признаку аутентификации, что опять возвращает нас к ID. Не уверен что существует кабинет для гостевого пользователя.

Comment: @Pekor `Where()` лишний.

Comment: Where() не может быть лишним!!! Иначе выводится какой то первый результат из таблицы пользователей...показывать какой-то результат так себе решение...а держать таблицу пользователя ради одной записи, аналогично будет плохим решение